# How to exclude custom extension JS : Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, javascript, merge-css

I want to exclude some custom extension JS from merge functionality. so how can i achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Tyr this solution, Exclude js file from the merge by adding the js file in **Theme_Directory/etc/view.xml**

```
<exclude>
    <!-- To exclude whole directory -->
    <item type="directory">RH_Helloworld::js</item>
    <!-- To exclude specific file -->
    <item type="file">RH_Helloworld::jquery/jquery.min.js</item>
</exclude>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you want to remove it on specific page or globally, the principle is the same. On layout file, add the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <remove src="js/custom.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```