Stripe payment button not loaded when enable the bundling, merge_files for js
After enabling the merge_files and js_bundling options in Magento, the Stripe Express Checkout button no longer appears. Additionally, the debugger is not being triggered, and the StripeIntegration_Payments/js script is not loading in my browser. However, when I disable the merge_files and js_bundling options, everything functions as expected.
 require(['domReady!', 'StripeIntegration_Payments/js/stripe_payments_express', 'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'], function(domReady, stripeExpress, customerData) {
            debugger;
 })


Check or try to exclude stripe js from bundling or merging:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/145345/magento-2-js-bundling-exclude-certain-script
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/367673/how-to-exclude-custom-extension-js-magento-2-4

I have already tried these solutions. Specifically, I added a view.xml file in the etc folder under {Magento root}/app/design/frontend/MyCompany/MyWebsite/etc/view.xml, but there were no changes. I also ran setup:upgrade, compile, deploy, cache:clean, and restarted the server, but the issue persists.
The Stripe module is still bundled in the default.min.js file.  The xml file contain below code.
<exclude><item type="file">StripeIntegration_Payments::js/stripe_payments_express.js</item>         <item type="directory">StripeIntegration_Payments::js</item>  </exclude>
